# draw matplotlib rectangle patch with infinite length

Tags: matplotlib, patch

I can't seem to find a way to draw a rectangle patch with infinite side length in matplotlib, nor can I find any documentation or conversations as to whether there is a way to do this.

basically:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
x_min = 0
x_range = 1
y_min = -np.inf
y_range = np.inf
Rectangle((x_min, y_min), x_range, y_range)
```

I realize that inf - inf in numpy returns nan, and that this is probably computed at some point.

Anyway, looking at the code for Rectangle didn't get me any closer to a solution, so I thought I'd check and see if anyone on here can think of a way around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you would rather have an `axhspan` or `axvspan`.  Example [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/axhspan_demo.html).

Comment: but how do you specify `axvspan(1, inf)` without it making the plot wider?